# Prev/Next Item button not working within Ng-Repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to build a simple "pager" app that allows you page from one json object to the next.

When adding the prev/next navigation outside of the repeat, it works fine.

When I try adding it within the ng-repeat, which I'm ultimately trying to accomplish, it no longer pages through. Oddly enough, I can see it's doing something as the prev/next buttons will disable if you're at beginning/end.

Here's demo illustrating the problem:
http://embed.plnkr.co/bR9BwrhDquvLV5TVMWtL/

Code inside ng-repeat (Top Prev/Next Buttons):

```
<div class="a2a-accounts" ng-show="accounts.length">
    <div class="btn-group" role="toolbar" aria-label="First group">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-link" ng-disabled="curPage == 0" ng-click="curPage=curPage-1"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left fa-2x"></i> Prev </a>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-link" ng-disabled="curPage >= accounts.length/pageSize - 1" ng-click="curPage = curPage+1"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right fa-2x"></i> Next </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Code outside of ng-repeat (Bottom Prev/Next Buttons):

```
<div class="pagination pagination-centered" ng-show="accounts.length">
    <ul class="pagination-controle pagination">
        <li>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" ng-disabled="curPage == 0" ng-click="curPage=curPage-1"> &lt; PREV</button>
        </li>
        <li>
            <span>Page {{curPage + 1}} of {{ numberOfPages() }}</span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" ng-disabled="curPage >= accounts.length/pageSize - 1" ng-click="curPage = curPage+1">NEXT &gt;</button>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Can someone explain how to make this work within the ng-repeat?

Comment: Read about scopes. You're modifying the `curPage` variable within the `ng-repeat` scope, and you want to modify it in the `$parent` scope. If you don't want to read about scopes, then `$parent.curPage = $parent.curPage - 1`.

Comment: Hi @fedeisas, can you be more specific or share a link or example?

Comment: @fedeisas, sorry I must have commented before you added the details about adding $parent. I actually tried that too, but I must have been doing it incorrectly. thanks!

Comment: what does start = +start mean in this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ng-repeat` creates a new scope for every row it iterates over.  Without a dot in your angular bindings, primitives like `curPage` will be bound to the scope which they exist in.  This means that the `curPage` inside each row of the `ng-repeat` are separate variables, and also separate from the `curPage` value outside the `ng-repeat`.

To ensure that every instance is pointing to the same thing, you need to have an object property that you bind to in the parent scope.

http://plnkr.co/edit/VMrRqJxndVqIfkPAIMZf?p=preview

Comment: similar response as presented above. thanks to you both

Comment: as a general rule of thumb, you should **always use a dot in angular bindings**.